# Why does the second call to RasGetEntryProperties() return an Overlapped I/O operation is in progress?

Tags: c, winapi

There is such code:

```
#include <ras.h>
#include <raserror.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    DWORD dwEntryInfoSize = 0;
    DWORD dwDeviceInfoSize = 0;
    DWORD dwRet = 0;
    LPRASENTRY lpRasEntry = NULL;
    LPBYTE lpDeviceInfo = NULL;
```

Create RAS connection. Get buffer sizing information for a default phonebook entry.

```
    if ((dwRet = RasGetEntryProperties(NULL, "", NULL, &dwEntryInfoSize, NULL, &dwDeviceInfoSize)) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        if (dwRet != ERROR_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL) {
            printf("RasGetEntryProperties error: %s\n", GetLastError());

            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    if (dwEntryInfoSize == 0) {
        printf("Entry info size error: %s\n", GetLastError());

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }


    lpRasEntry = (LPRASENTRY) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, dwEntryInfoSize);

    if (lpRasEntry == NULL) {
        printf("HeapAlloc RasEntry error: %s\n", GetLastError());

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (dwDeviceInfoSize) {
        lpDeviceInfo = (LPBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, dwDeviceInfoSize);
    }

    lpRasEntry->dwSize = sizeof(RASENTRY);
```

Here there is an error: Overlapped I/O operation is in progress. The error occurs in Windows XP and in Windows 10 everything works fine. I need this code to work in XP.

```
    if ((dwRet = RasGetEntryProperties(NULL, "", lpRasEntry, &dwEntryInfoSize, lpDeviceInfo, &dwDeviceInfoSize)) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        printf("RasGetEntryProperties error: %s\n", GetLastError());

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Validate new phonebook name "TestEntry"
    if ((dwRet = RasValidateEntryName(NULL, "TestEntry")) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        printf("RasValidateEntryName error: %s\n", GetLastError());

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Install a new phonebook entry, "TestEntry", using default properties
    if ((dwRet = RasSetEntryProperties(NULL, "TestEntry", lpRasEntry, dwEntryInfoSize, lpDeviceInfo, dwDeviceInfoSize)) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        printf("RasSetEntryProperties error: %s\n", GetLastError());

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Deallocate memory for the connection buffer
    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, lpRasEntry);
    lpRasEntry = NULL;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This code creates a dial-up connection. And I'm stuck on this bug.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSuZH.png)

Comment: `RasGetEntryProperties` not set last error. it **return** error code. so call `GetLastError()` after `RasGetEntryProperties` is senseless. you need print `dwRet` instead

Comment: Thank you very much! I fully explained the nature of the error below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code showed errors...

Error #1: The Ras* functions do not set error codes for GetLastError(). Those GetLastError() does not make sense. They return error codes as DWORD. Read Routing and Remote Access Error Codes in MSDN.

Error #2: Starting with NT in the RasGetEntryProperties() function 5 and 6, the parameters are not used and should be NULL.

Error #3: The most insidious. The fact is that the size of the RASENTRY structure for some Windows operating systems is different. For example, between XP and 10. Therefore, somewhere in the header files, we should specify something like this:

```
#define WINVER 0x0501
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
```

More details can be read in MSDN. Modifying WINVER and _WIN32_WINNT. In this case, we specified the version of Windows XP. That's what I needed. And Overlapped I / O operation is in progress has nothing to do with us in this case. We just output the result of GetLastError() which probably arose somewhere in the depths of Windows when the previous functions were executed.